# Why does the form only open/display when the CTRL key is used with the link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to resolve why an html form will *only* open, open meaning showing the login fields, when the request is made with the CTRL key?.  A little bizarre.  This is the form in question.

In other words - choosing the link from a menu normally (normally = not holding down the CTRL key) results in the file/form not displaying the login fields - loading the a blank file/form.

Choose *Heat for Edutech staff* from the *Helpdesk* menu here [edutech.org](http://edutech.org)
and then try the same thing, only using the CTRL key the next time.  The form should open and display the fields without the benefit of the CTRL key.

Chrome reports this error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://heatweb.edutech.org:8180" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://edutech.org". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

I'm sure this is the problem, just not sure how to solve it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Call Logging</title>


     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://heatweb.edutech.org:8180/HeatWebUI/calllogging/CallLogging.html"/> -->
   
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="calllogging.nocache.js">

 alert('hi');
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

   (function()
          {
           if( window.localStorage )
            {
             if( !localStorage.getItem( 'firstLoad' ) )
            {
             localStorage[ 'firstLoad' ] = true;
              window.location.reload();
            }  
             else
              localStorage.removeItem( 'firstLoad' );
            }
           })();
 
 </script>

</head>


<body oncontextmenu="return false;">

        <iframe id="RSIFrame_1"  name="RSIFrame_1" style="width:0px; height:0px; border: 0px" src="javascript:''"></iframe>

        <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
</body>


</html>
```

I added the html refresh meta tag (commented out ) and the javascript reload function.  I have tried other similar javascript window relocation attempts but nothing changes the outcome.  The page/form loads as a blank form - the login fields do not display unless I do one of two things.

1 - copy and paste the link to the callLogging.html file into a new browser tab

2 - Hold down the CTRL key while clicking the link that is attempting to load the form.

The behavior is the same in any of the windows browsers I have tried (FF 39.0.3, Chrome 44.0.2403.155, IE 11).

I have also tried these html and javascript solutions, with no change in behavior or the loading file.

[image]

I would like to solve the mystery of why the form fields do not display upon initial form load OR if there is a way to simulate the CTRL key depression with the link click.

Thank you for any insights - suggestions.

Comment: Can you please post the code using code format instead of images? It's hard to see like that.

Comment: Could you copy your source into the post rather than using images?

Comment: I can see the form when I go to http://heatweb.edutech.org:8180/HeatWebUI/calllogging/CallLogging.html

Comment: Ctrl+click is a common shortcut to open links in a new window/tab. Your scripting could may being called upon such event only.

Comment: I can see the form when I click on the link in your post. I also see two errors in the browser console: `Uncaught Reference Error: Ext is not defined`

Comment: I added the form code as code, not image.  I realize that the CTRL key is a common shortcut to open a link in a new tab.  What I need is for the form to open correctly - displaying the fields - WITHOUT the CTRL key being clicked.

Comment: I can't see the login form, neither using CTRL or not using it. I get a blank page with two errors: 1) Ext is not defined (twice) and 2) Blocked a frame with origin "http://heatweb.edutech.org:8180" from accessing a frame with origin "http://edutech.org". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. Chrome 44.0.2403.155 m

Comment: thanks Alvaro, i did not see that happening in Chrome - the debug info is helpful - hopefully will lend itself to a solution or workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to clear the error that Chrome reported, which lead to the workaround which I was finally able to understand by reading [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dthorpe/archive/2007/09/27/cross-domain-communication-using-domain-lowering.aspx) about "**Domain lowering**"

error reported by Chrome:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://heatweb.edutech.org:8180" from accessing a frame with origin "http://edutech.org". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

I added this javascript statement to the source (calling) file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  document.domain = "edutech.org";
  window.location = "http://heatweb.edutech.org:8180/HeatWebUI/calllogging/CallLogging.html";
</script>
```